# CORS 500 Error on Preflight response TinyMCE Image upload

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cors, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and trying to upload an Image.My HTML page is being served by Django. Please see below my image upload handler (provided by TinyMCE)

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
            var xhr, formData;

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/tiny_upload.php');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest')
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
            };

            xhr.onload = function () {
                var json;

                if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }

                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                    failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }

                success(json.location);
            };

            xhr.onerror = function () {
                failure('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status +
                    ' Message:' + xhr.responseText);
            };

            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            xhr.send(formData);
        }
```

And my uploader php is below

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
/***************************************************
 * Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
 ***************************************************/
$accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://127.0.0.1:8000", "http://127.0.0.1");

/*********************************************
 * Change this line to set the upload folder *
 *********************************************/
$imageFolder = "images/";
reset($_FILES);
$temp = current($_FILES);
header('CUS_MSG: hello');
if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])) {
    header('CUS_MSG1: hello');
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
        if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
            return;
        }
    }

    /*
    If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
    the configuration and enable the following two headers.
     */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
} else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
}
?>
```

Issue here is that the PreFlight request always fails with 500 Error. However I dont get this when i run the same in Chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag

[image]

Error on Chrome console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/tiny_upload.php' from
> origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
> does not have HTTP ok status.

Please help in this issue. This happens in Local WAMP server as well as Apache server on Centos machine

Comment: I tried adding a lot of other headers as well for Allow-Headers , Allow-Methods, Request-Headers, Request-Methods by setting value as *. No luck

Comment: In you `php`-code I've seen only one place where the script return the `500`-code. It happens when the function `is_uploaded_file` returning not `true`-value. What exactly do this function?

Comment: is_uploaded_file checks if the file was submitted via POST, one thing what i have observed in preflight request (request method OPTIONS) it doesn't send the file and first expects a response with CORS headers after which the actual POST request is sent with the file.

Comment: Yes, it is. First of all ajax sending the `OPTIONS`-request to make sure the ajax-request have permission to send cross origin request. CORS-headers sended back to the `OPTIONS-request`, and it is in your code, but `OPTIONS` has no files and your `if`-statement go to `else`-branch that return `500`-code.

So, try to specify action for 'OPTIONS'-request. If script get 'OPTIONS' make `exit`, for example.

Comment: @Evgeniy Thanks very much for this. I'll give it a try

Comment: @Evgeniy It worked !! :-) :-) Thanks very much again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Evgeniy for the reply in comments.

I changed the php file content to the below

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
/***************************************************
 * Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
 ***************************************************/
$accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://127.0.0.1:8000", "http://127.0.0.1");

/*********************************************
 * Change this line to set the upload folder *
 *********************************************/

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            return;
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
            return;
        }
    }
} elseif ($method == 'POST') {
    $imageFolder = "images/";
    reset($_FILES);
    $temp = current($_FILES);
    if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])) {
        header('CUS_MSG1: hello');
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
            if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
            } else {
                header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
                return;
            }
        }

        /*
    If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
    the configuration and enable the following two headers.
     */
        // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

        // Sanitize input
        if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
            return;
        }

        // Verify extension
        if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
            return;
        }

        // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
        $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

        // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
        // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
        // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
        echo json_encode(array('location' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $filetowrite));
    } else {
        // Notify editor that the upload failed
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    }
} else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
}
?>
```

and removed `xhr.setRequestHeader('x-requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest')` from the JS file